# How to identify invalid dates in postgres table field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL that has two date fields ( start and end ). There are many invalid dates both date fields like 0988-08-11,4987-09-11 etc.. Is there a simple query to identify them? The data type of the field is DATE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A column defined as `date` can not contain invalid dates.

Comment: What is your definition of an "invalid date"?

Comment: The dates in your question look just fine...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : These incorrect dates entered the system using some old tool. The manual input does not accept this format. I am trying to find out these bad dates and delete them. Thanks.

Comment: @Nicarus: They are not correct dates. 0988 and 4987 are not valid years.

Comment: ,@Laurenz Albe : 0988 and 4987 are not valid years

Comment: They are valid years - what makes you think they aren't?

Comment: select all the dates that are not between a min and a max date (a range of "valid" dates according to your business logic).

Answer (score 1):

Values in a date column *ARE* valid per definition. The year `0988 = 988` is a valid historic date as well as the year `4987` which is far in the future.

To filter out dates which are too historic or too far in the future you simply make this query:

```
SELECT 
    date_col        
FROM
    table
WHERE 
       date_col < /* <MINIMUM DATE> */ 
    OR date_col > /* <MAXIMUM DATE> */
```

---

For date ranges (your minimum and maximum date) you could use the daterange functionality:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

**Example table**:

```
start_date    end_date
2015-01-01    2017-01-01   -- valid
 200-01-01     900-01-01   -- completely too early
3000-01-01    4000-01-01   -- completely too late
0200-01-01    2000-01-01   -- begin too early
2000-01-01    4000-01-01   -- end too late
 200-01-01    4000-01-01   -- begin too early, end too late
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT 
    start_date, 
    end_date 
FROM 
    dates 
WHERE 
    daterange('1900-01-01', '2100-01-01') @> daterange(start_date, end_date)
```

**Result**:

```
start_date    end_date
2015-01-01    2017-01-01
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7eff9b58a3b500b26811ec22005a091e)

Comment: Thank you so much. It should help. The organization is just 20 years old and the start and end of an employee can't be 988 or 4987.

Answer (score 0):

Those are valid dates, but if you have business rules that state they are not valid for your purpose, you can delete them based on those rules:

For example, if you don't want any dates prior to 1900 or after 2999, this statement would delete the records with those dates:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE
    start_date < '1900-01-01'::DATE OR
    start_date >= '2999-01-01'::DATE OR
    end_date < '1900-01-01'::DATE OR
    end_date >= '2999-01-01'::DATE;
```

If you want to replace the dates with the lowest/highest acceptable dates instead of deleting the entire record, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET
    start_date = least('2999-01-01'::DATE, greatest('1900-01-01'::DATE, start_date)),
    end_date = least('2999-01-01'::DATE, greatest('1900-01-01'::DATE, end_date))
WHERE
    start_date < '1900-01-01'::DATE OR
    start_date >= '2999-01-01'::DATE OR
    end_date < '1900-01-01'::DATE OR
    end_date >= '2999-01-01'::DATE;
```